# Cannot link Google Search Console (GSC) to Google Analytics (GA)

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-search-console

I've added my website to GSC and GA. But when I'm trying to link GSC with GA it says "you haven't verified any sites". My website doesn't show on here.

Answer (score 1):

It may happens when you're using a Property that's been verified as a *domain* instead of a *URL prefix*.  Verify the Property as a URL prefix, for the version of the site that's indexed in Google, and try again.